# How to remove the same columns in multiple arrays using loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have several NumPy arrays which I wanted to remove the column in each arrays. The index of the columsn is same for all arrays.

I wrote this code and it didn't work.

```
list= [a1, a2, a3]

for arrry in list:
        arrry  = np.delete(arrry, [0, 1, 2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that Python is call-by-name.
When you do

```
arrry = np.delete(arrry, [0, 1, 2], axis=1)
```

you're assigning the name `arrry` to the new array with the missing column, but are not changing the list.
try:

```
list= [a1, a2, a3]

for idx, arrry in enumerate(list):
        list[idx] = np.delete(arrry, [0, 1, 2], axis=1)
```

Comment: I realized that, when I call "a1" again, it not showing the modified array. Instead, list[0] will show. Is there any way to simply call a1?

Comment: Not really, because `np.delete` returns a new array, hance `list[0]` no longer points to the same array as a1. I don't know what your complete code is supposed to do, but chances are you should probably use the list from the start, rather than using a1, a2, a3 separately.

Answer (score 1):

you can do a list comprehension,

```
lst = [np.arange(100,112).reshape(2,6),np.arange(12).reshape(2,6)]
>>>lst
[array([[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
       [106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111]]), 
 array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
]

lst = [np.delete(x, [0, 1, 2], axis=1)for x in lst]
>>>lst
[array([[103, 104, 105],
        [109, 110, 111]]), 
 array([[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 9, 10, 11]])
]
```